# Minecraft updater keeps crashing and the client exits

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

macos V12.0.1 Macbook air 2020 m1 chip

When I try and open minecraft, it opens for a split second then shuts down from what can tell it's the updater when it first runs. (no error/warning screens)

I googled and came across an article about couple of people were experiencing the same issue but they deleted the "application support/minecraft" folder or they ran the launcher inside of the "show app contents" > "macos" folder in parallel with the app running.

In my case both solutions don't work.

I provided the logs below

launcher_log

```
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.620054: NetQueue.cpp(157)] NetQueue: Setting up.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.620568: NetQueue.cpp(575)] NetQueue: worker thread started.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.620647: mainOSX.cpp.mm(54)] Running launcher bootstrap (version 973)
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.631417: Settings.cpp(40)] Failed to determine configuration file size: No such file or directory
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634810: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download <game>. Please try again later."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634830: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634842: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634851: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634860: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634955: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634966: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634974: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to relaunch the Minecraft bootstrap."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634982: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start the <game> Runtime Environment. This is most likely caused by a corruption. Please try to reinstall <game>."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634991: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start <game>, if you are running from a dmg, please drag to Applications and try again."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.634999: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to initialize the network library."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.635006: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "<game> Launcher"
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.635034: Common.cpp(32)] Native Launcher Version: 973
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.635046: Common.cpp(33)] Operating System: OSX Version 10.16 (Build 21A559)
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636730: Common.cpp(34)] Application Data directory: //.../minecraft
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636757: Common.cpp(35)] Executable Path: //.../launcher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636769: Common.cpp(36)] App Directory dir: //.../Contents
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636780: Common.cpp(37)] Game data directory: //.../minecraft
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636791: Common.cpp(38)] Launcher dir: //.../launcher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636802: Common.cpp(39)] Java dir: //.../jre-x64
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636813: Common.cpp(40)] TmpDir dir: //.../MinecraftLauncher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.636824: Common.cpp(41)] x64: true
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.638123: NetQueue.cpp(157)] NetQueue: Setting up.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.638765: NetQueue.cpp(575)] NetQueue: worker thread started.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.638813: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(292)] Using update preferences at path: .../minecraft/launcher_profiles.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.638852: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(306)] Using update preferences at path: .../minecraft/launcher_settings.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.639027: NetQueue.cpp(585)] NetQueue: Starting net action launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846337: NetQueue.cpp(428)] NetQueue: Primary ip: 13.224.182.128, Host: launchermeta.mojang
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846384: NetQueue.cpp(504)] NetQueue: Action finished: launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846402: NetQueue.cpp(532)] NetQueue: Action finalized: launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846937: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(198)] Deciding on update with strategy 0 and clientID 0
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846976: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(219)] We should change launcher-bootstrap from 973 to 1036
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.846999: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(238)] launcher-bootstrap update is needed.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.847027: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(261)] Error opening: .../minecraft/launcher/.version, Error message: No such file or directory
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.847054: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(198)] Deciding on update with strategy 0 and clientID 0
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.847071: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(219)] We should change launcher-core-v2 from unknown to 2.2.8543
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.847088: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(238)] launcher-core-v2 update is needed.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:05.847110: mainOSX.cpp.mm(110)] We need to update - starting the updater.
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.674264: mainOSX.cpp.mm(130)] Updater failed for some reason... exiting with error.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.675196: NetQueue.cpp(585)] NetQueue: Starting net action sentry.io/api/2705241/store/
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.675316: NetQueue.cpp(183)] NetQueue: Initiating shutdown.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.675333: NetQueue.cpp(197)] NetQueue: Waiting for worker thread to finish...
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.675363: NetQueue.cpp(689)] NetQueue: Worker thread shutting down.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.676005: NetQueue.cpp(200)] NetQueue: Done.
```

nativeUpdaterLog

```
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.495216: Settings.cpp(40)] Failed to determine configuration file size: No such file or directory
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498544: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download <game>. Please try again later."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498587: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498598: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498608: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498616: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498625: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498635: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498643: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to relaunch the Minecraft bootstrap."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498652: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start the <game> Runtime Environment. This is most likely caused by a corruption. Please try to reinstall <game>."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498732: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start <game>, if you are running from a dmg, please drag to Applications and try again."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498743: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to initialize the network library."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.498752: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "<game> Launcher"
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.500160: NetQueue.cpp(157)] NetQueue: Setting up.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.501624: NetQueue.cpp(575)] NetQueue: worker thread started.
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510189: Settings.cpp(40)] Failed to determine configuration file size: No such file or directory
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510301: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download <game>. Please try again later."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510314: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510323: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510331: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to download the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510339: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Game Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510347: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Runtime Environment."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510355: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to update the <game> Native Launcher."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510363: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to relaunch the Minecraft bootstrap."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510371: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start the <game> Runtime Environment. This is most likely caused by a corruption. Please try to reinstall <game>."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510379: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to start <game>, if you are running from a dmg, please drag to Applications and try again."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510387: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "Unable to initialize the network library."
[Error: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510395: localization.cpp(110)] No translation found for "<game> Launcher"
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510444: Common.cpp(32)] Native Launcher Version: 973
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510455: Common.cpp(33)] Operating System: OSX Version 10.16 (Build 21A559)
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510471: Common.cpp(34)] Application Data directory: //.../minecraft
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510495: Common.cpp(35)] Executable Path: //.../launcher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510515: Common.cpp(36)] App Directory dir: //.../Contents
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510526: Common.cpp(37)] Game data directory: //.../minecraft
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510537: Common.cpp(38)] Launcher dir: //.../launcher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510547: Common.cpp(39)] Java dir: //.../jre-x64
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510558: Common.cpp(40)] TmpDir dir: //.../MinecraftLauncher
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510569: Common.cpp(41)] x64: true
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510691: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(292)] Using update preferences at path: //.../launcher_profiles.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.510711: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(306)] Using update preferences at path: //.../launcher_settings.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.511437: NetQueue.cpp(585)] NetQueue: Starting net action launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.577589: NetQueue.cpp(428)] NetQueue: Primary ip: 13.224.182.128, Host: launchermeta.mojang
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.577628: NetQueue.cpp(504)] NetQueue: Action finished: launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.577645: NetQueue.cpp(532)] NetQueue: Action finalized: launchermeta.mojang/v1/products/launcher/022631aeac4a9addbce8e0503dce662152dc198d/mac-os.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578276: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(198)] Deciding on update with strategy 0 and clientID 0
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578295: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(219)] We should change launcher-bootstrap from 973 to 1036
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578377: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(238)] launcher-bootstrap update is needed.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578445: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(261)] Error opening: //.../.version, Error message: No such file or directory
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578488: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(198)] Deciding on update with strategy 0 and clientID 0
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578502: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(219)] We should change launcher-core-v2 from unknown to 2.2.8543
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578514: LauncherConfiguration.cpp(238)] launcher-core-v2 update is needed.
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578532: main.cpp(81)] Updating bootstrap...
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578728: PistonUpdate.cpp(572)] Downloading launchermeta.mojang/v1/packages/6e52a1a4de78c6076513c49a5232a89fac4cebf1/manifest.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.578828: NetQueue.cpp(585)] NetQueue: Starting net action launchermeta.mojang/v1/packages/6e52a1a4de78c6076513c49a5232a89fac4cebf1/manifest.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.604127: NetQueue.cpp(428)] NetQueue: Primary ip: 13.224.182.128, Host: launchermeta.mojang
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.604197: NetQueue.cpp(504)] NetQueue: Action finished: launchermeta.mojang/v1/packages/6e52a1a4de78c6076513c49a5232a89fac4cebf1/manifest.json
[Info: 2022-01-12 05:24:06.604230: NetQueue.cpp(532)] NetQueue: Action finalized: launchermeta.mojang/v1/packages/6e52a1a4de78c6076513c49a5232a89fac4cebf1/manifest.json
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please give me a little bit more info so I can try to answer?

Comment: @readingminer thanks for your comment, i added some more info

Comment: That seems to be you're running on non-translated(or possibly bugged) language. What language are you on?

Comment: Did you try and delete Minecraft and then reinstall it?

Comment: yes, tried restarting, reinstall app. i sent a ticket off to microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/qxdkak/minecraft_nativeupdater_crash_macos_monterey_121/), using the [MultiMC launcher](https://multimc.org/) is a fix.

I'm experiencing the same issue and still need to check the MultiMC solution (I'm on an Intel-based Mac); I'll update this post when I have tested it.

BTW, this is a bug which is being tracked at the [Mojang Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-19830)

Update: The MultiMC solution works (for me)

Details/remarks:

- It works from scratch, I had uninstalled the crashing official launcher before installing MultiMC so no old Minecraft files were on my system
- I run an Intel based Macbook Air 2018 with OSX 12.1
- MultiMC may be blocked by OSX security settings; if this happens you can still allow it to run via Preferences > Security & Privacy > General
- Before running MultiMC you need to install Java version 17. The current, most recent version from [Oracle](https://java.com), version 18, does *not* work. Check the MultiMC FAQ for a solution, I ended up using the OpenJDK17 version from Microsoft ([linked from the FAQ](https://github.com/MultiMC/Launcher/wiki/Using-the-right-Java))
- When this is done, MultiMC should autodetect the Java version and you can install Minecraft via 'Add Instance'
- I chose the most recent version 1.18.1; this then downloads all required files from Mojang
- You also need to enter the details of you Mojang- or Microsoft-account (see also the (MultiMC FAQ)
- Start Minecraft by doubleclicking the icon in MultiMC

Good luck!